# Hybrid mobile applications unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cordova, sikuli, monkeytalk

It is noticed that there are difficulties to find a better testing tool for hybrid mobile applications , for native it is ok , but in the case of hybrid I am in a confusion to use which tool? Have anybody tried any better testing tool for hybrid apps?

Comment: So whats the problem then?

Comment: @MisterSmith : I mean working fine with android ..but Is it applicable to hybrid (javascript,html5,css) ?

Comment: I don't know this framework but at a first glance it seems it only allows testing Java code. For the JavaScript part you can use your favourite JS testing framework, for instance qUnit.

Comment: Thanks Smith ..and  what about jQuery and jQuery mobile?

Comment: These are javascript libraries. JQuery is mostly for utilities and DOM manipulation, while JQM is more about page changing and widget enhancement.

Comment: @MisterSmith : I have got two tools monkey talk and Sikuli , got any idea about them ? or any suggestions ? If do please let me know.    Regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution of my own ,I just come across some tools like **[Monkey Talk](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk/)**  **[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)** **[Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/)** **[Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/)** **[QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/)** and **[expect.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/expect.js/)** (preferable Mocha with expect.js)haven't tried these but the documentation describes it is useful for hybrid application testing. 
If there is someone who have used these tools , Share some information from your experience.

Regards :)